# Ceck speed internet with ifconfig?

Tags: linux, ubuntu, ifconfig

I have some problem about Linux network statistics,
How to get internet speed Up/Down use command line on terminal Linux Ubuntu?
if command like this :

```
$ ifconfig eth0 | grep 'RX bytes:'
```

and value is

```
RX bytes:0 (0.0 B)  TX bytes:0 (0.0 B)
```

but i want value Upstream/downstream.

How to get value like this:

```
UP 20 Kb/s
DOWN 45 Kb/s
```

Comment: You can't, not with a single command. those are counters. you'd need to check at least twice and then do some math. `((bytes @ time2) - (bytes @time1)) / seconds between measurements`

Comment: https://github.com/sivel/speedtest-cli

Comment: Are you interested in the current Up/Downstream or do you want to know how fast your connection is?

Comment: No, this is part of my quiz,